# Django column does not exist error when created a mixed-case or upper-case column name

Tags: django, postgresql

```
class uretimkaynaklari(models.Model):

    tarih = models.DateField()
    malzemeNo = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    operasyonKodu = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    isyeri = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    vardiya = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    sicil = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    uretimMiktari = models.FloatField()
    uretimSuresiMakina = models.FloatField()
    uretimSuresiIscilik = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sicil


def operatoranalizi_func(request):

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""SELECT id as id, tarih as tarih, sicil as sicil, uretimSuresiMakina as uretimSuresiMakina
            FROM operatoranalizi_uretimkaynaklari """)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    print(rows)
    return HttpResponse("success")
```

when ı get only "id", "tarih", "isyeri" columns everything is ok but when ı want to get "uretimsuresimakina" column ı got error column does not exist.

Comment: Possibly you forgot makemigrations and migrate.

Comment: I did it also table has data @SarojRai.

Comment: As convention, your model names should be CamelCase, start with an upper-case letter. And your fields should be all lower case, and there should be "_" between words. It should be "uretim_suresi_makina". And in my humble opinion, you should name your fields in english, you can use "verbose_name" to translate it. Like: `is_moderated = models.BooleanField("Moderatör Onayı", default=False)`

Comment: and in Django you should not use raw sql for that simple query. Use django ORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT "id" as id, "tarih" as tarih, "sicil" as sicil, "uretimSuresiMakina" as uretimSuresiMakina
            FROM operatoranalizi_uretimkaynaklari """)
```

Thanks. I added double quotes for mixed-case or upper-case column name. There is no error.